# Schema - Diagram creator mongodb

Tags: mongodb, graphics, schema, database

i need to create a schema with all the models of my DB.
I'm using ROR with **mongodb**.

I'm actually looking for a tool to draw something like this :

[image: http://talks.php.net/presentations/slides/mongodb/blog2.png]

Any Suggestion ? or i've to open paint and adapt ?

Comment: Are you just trying to find a diagramming application so you can create this manually, or looking for an application to work out the diagram for you (i.e. by inspecting the database)?  If you're looking for an application, what O/S(es) do you need this for?

Comment: I need to create it manually (because they're no tools existing to "reverse" from ROR's models using Mongoid). I can use All OS : windows (7) - Unix (Fedora) and Mac (OS X Lion). btw i take a look at Visio and it seems great.

Comment: Actually, suspect there may be something possible.  Not sure how far [railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady) goes, but it's one such option that does apparently work with Mongoid.  With a scriptable app like OmniGraffle you could bling up the output nicely :).

Comment: I am wondering if you eventually got your answer. If so, could you update your post?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

http://www.draw.io/

draw.io is a free online diagramming application designed around Google Drive for workflow, BPM, org charts, UML, ER, network diagrams and more.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.gliffy.com/

Today I am using the Glyffy. I adopted as modeling a model like yours, and the great advantage that is realized in glyffy can use directly in Google Drive can share the model with other users.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Visio, as its more flexible. If its purpose is only to do representative figures Visio or even Dia should do the necessary help. If you would like to develop model out of it it won't be possible.

Comment: Please also refer to this [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272816/what-is-a-good-visio-enterprise-architect-replacement which refers to good alternatives of Visio which also you can consider.

Comment: [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/) is a reasonable (and free) cross-platform choice. I've also seen similar diagrams created with [LibreOffice (née OpenOffice) Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/). If you're using OS X then [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) is a great commercial app for creating diagrams (and scriptable via AppleScript if you want to try creating programmatically).